# Disappearing Comments

Tags: discussion, comments

Why do comments disappear on some questions? I posed a quiestion last night (No Code First option when adding new model) and there was one comment and an answer which contained a link and now both have disappeared.

Comment: They've most likely been deleted, either by the community or the original poster.

Comment: I am the poster and I didnlt delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That comment was deleted by the person who left it. Perhaps they felt it was no longer needed, or otherwise inappropriate.

In regards to the answer, here it is, in its entirety:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/data/jj200620 provides you with a very nice step-by-step guide. Good luck :)

The following comment was left on that:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

and it was downvoted, at which point the person who left it deleted their own answer.

Comment: Ah ok. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding comments:

1. Users can delete their own comments.
2. Moderators can remove the comments too, that happens usually in the case of flagged comments.

And the [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBV8r.png) in your case was deleted by the user himself.